# Can't Apache2 start erorr: Can't locate SOAP/Transport/HTTP.pm

Tags: apache, perl

I have a problem with apache2 start.

When I try apache start i have the message:

```
root@ocsi:/var/log/apache2# **systemctl start apache2.service**
Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

---

**in systemctl status apache2.service**

```
root@ocsi:/var/log/apache2# systemctl status apache2.service
● apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2020-06-01 07:53:07 CEST; 19s ago
       Docs: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/
    Process: 3142 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jun 01 07:53:07 ocsi systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Jun 01 07:53:07 ocsi apachectl[3142]: Action 'start' failed.
Jun 01 07:53:07 ocsi apachectl[3142]: The Apache error log may have more information.
Jun 01 07:53:07 ocsi systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jun 01 07:53:07 ocsi systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jun 01 07:53:07 ocsi systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
```

---

**in journalctl -xe**

```
root@ocsi:/var/log/apache2# journalctl -xe
Jun 01 07:54:31 ocsi multipathd[700]: sda: add missing path
Jun 01 07:54:31 ocsi multipathd[700]: sda: failed to get udev uid: Invalid argument
Jun 01 07:54:31 ocsi multipathd[700]: sda: failed to get sysfs uid: Invalid argument
Jun 01 07:54:31 ocsi multipathd[700]: sda: failed to get sgio uid: No such file or directory
```

---

**and in apache2 log is:**

root@ocsi:/var/log/apache2# vi error.log

```
[Mon Jun 01 07:53:07.305344 2020] [perl:error] [pid 3149] Can't locate SOAP/Transport/HTTP.pm in @INC (you may need to install the SOAP::Transport::HTTP module) (@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.30.0 /usr/local/share/perl/5.30.0 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.30 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.30 /usr/share/perl/5.30 /usr/local/lib/site_perl /etc/apache2) at /usr/local/share/perl/5.30.0/Apache/Ocsinventory/Plugins/Apache.pm line 25.\nBEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/share/perl/5.30.0/Apache/Ocsinventory/Plugins/Apache.pm line 25.\nCompilation failed in require at (eval 16) line 1.\n
[Mon Jun 01 07:53:07.305621 2020] [perl:error] [pid 3149] Can't load Perl module Apache::Ocsinventory::Plugins::Apache for server localhost:0, exiting...
```

> My system:
>
> PHP Version : 7.4.3
>
> Server version: Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu)
>
> Description:    Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
>
> Ubuntu Linux 5.4.0-33-generic x86_64

How can I fix this error?

Comment: *"Can't locate SOAP/Transport/HTTP.pm"* Have you tried to install the module [SOAP::Lite](https://metacpan.org/pod/SOAP::Lite) ? The [Soap-Lite](https://metacpan.org/release/SOAP-Lite) distribution provides the module `SOAP::Transport::HTTP`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you need to install the SOAP::Lite module. That can be done by running:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libsoap-lite-perl
```

For more details, read on.

The error message is telling you that the Perl compiler can't find the module SOAP::Transport::HTTP (which is presumably used in some code used in your Apache start-up).

This module has never been part of a standard Perl distribution (you can test that by running `corelist SOAP::Transport::HTTP`). It, therefore, needs to be installed separately.

Perl modules are usually installed from [CPAN](https://metacpan.org/). If you search for the module there, you'll see it's part of the [SOAP-Lite](https://metacpan.org/release/PHRED/SOAP-Lite-1.27) distribution. Now you could install it directly from there using `cpan` but, given in this case, the easier approach is probably to install the pre-built package for your operating system. And that's done by running the command above.

Comment: Re "*the easier approach*", And safer. Upgrades to Perl will also upgrade the module. When using a package-managed `perl` (such as the system `perl`), best to use the same package manager for modules for that `perl`.

Comment: Thank You Dave Cross for Your support. I've installed SOAP module and after that Apache wake up